# Geofence Not Getting Triggered

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps-api-3, android-geofence

I am trying to add geofence when I receive it in `FirebaseMessagingService`. I am successfully able to add a geofence but for some reason, it doesn't fire. I have tried to debug and see what the problem is. But I simply can't figure out what the problem is. If anyone can point out the mistake. I would highly appreciate it.

This is my **manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<service
            android:name=".GeofenceTrasitionService"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Now when I receive that particular message to add a geofence only then I add it in my `onReceive().`

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i(TAG, "message_received");
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String messageType = data.get("messageType");
        switch (messageType) {
            case "NewLocationAdded": {
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
                        @Override
                        public void subscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
                            GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE_STRING = data.get("locationid");
                            locationName = data.get("locationname");
                            interval = Long.parseLong(data.get("interval"));
                            fastestInterval = Long.parseLong(data.get("fastestinterval"));
                            locationRadius = Long.parseLong(data.get("locationradius"));
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserDetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            DatabaseReference databaseReference = com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
                                    .getInstance()
                                    .getReference("Locations" + "/" + sharedPreferences.getString("UserID", "") + "/" + GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE_STRING);
                            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
                            geoFire.getLocation("Location", new LocationCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                                    x = location.latitude;
                                    y = location.longitude;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
                            latLng = new LatLng(x, y);
                            createGoogleApi();
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        }
                    }).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                   //Show Notitfication To Give Permission
                }
                break;
            }
    }
```

This works as expected. and when my `mGoogleApiClient` is connected I add my `geofence`.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
        startLocationUpdates();
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence(latLng, locationRadius, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE_STRING);
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
        addGeofence(geofenceRequest);
    }
```

I will include the above-written functions for clarity. What they do is pretty staright forward.

```
// Create GoogleApiClient instance
    private void createGoogleApi() {
        Log.i(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    // Start location Updates
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(300)
                .setFastestInterval(200);

        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

 // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius, String locationid) {
        Log.i(TAG, "createGeofence");
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(locationid)
                .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                        | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .setLoiteringDelay(30)
                .build();
    }

    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        Log.i(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .build();
    }

    // Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.i(TAG, "addGeofence");
        if (checkPermission()) {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, request, createGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                saveGeofence();
                                //     drawGeofence();
                            } else {
                                Log.i(TAG, "I failed in addGeofence()");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.i(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        if (geoFencePendingIntent != null)
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private void saveGeofence() {
        Log.i(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Locations", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.contains("GeofenceReqIDs")) {
            stringArrayList.addAll(sharedPreferences.getStringSet("GeofenceReqIDs", null));
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        stringArrayList.add(GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE_STRING);
        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
        stringSet.addAll(stringArrayList);
        editor.putStringSet("GeofenceReqIDs", stringSet);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

I know I have shared a lot of code, but I did it for clarity to my problem. I also posted logs. Lemme share them as well.

```
checkPermission()
createGoogleApi()
Connected to GoogleApiClient
startLocationUpdates()
checkPermission()
createGeofence
createGeofenceRequest
addGeofence
checkPermission()
createGeofencePendingIntent
onLocationChanged [Location[fused 25.314668,55.495936 acc=21 et=+5d3h47m13s84ms]]
onResult: Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}
saveGeofence()
```

If anyone can point out the problem. I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Maybe not the problem, but the unit of time used for most parameters 
 in LocationServices is milliseconds.  Many of your values seem small:  `setLoiteringDelay(30)`, `setInterval(300)`, etc.

Comment: i kept those values for debugging purposes only, using big numbers also dont work

Comment: Your log for `createGeofence` should include the lat, lng, and radius of the fence.  Without those, your logs for `onLocationChanged` aren't much help because you can't see if you've entered the fence.

Comment: the values are 

`long: 55.49614638090134`
`lat: 25.31433950917147`
`radius: 500`

Comment: You didn't post the code for your `GeofenceTrasitionService`.  How do you know it's not receiving transition events?  Absence of log messages?

Comment: because I put a Log in `onHandleIntent()` which is not getting displayed

Comment: In your Location settings, is Mode set to GPS Only?  If so, change it.  The troubleshooting section in [the Geofencing Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) says, _On most devices, the geofence service uses only network location for geofence triggering_

Comment: after I set `initialTrigger()` as `Geofence.EXITING` it worked but it shouldn't have worked for `EXITING` since I am inside the `Geofence`

Comment: Where does "geoFencePendingIntent" get declared?